# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax - not exist - xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have made a sql statement that works normal in a shared server. but since I migrated the database to a local one

it showing a #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

```
INSERT INTO shops (shop_name, googleid, address, city, country, open_now, logogroup, idshopgroup, shop_group, image, website) 
select '$shopname', '".$key["googleid"]."','$address','".$key["city"]."', 
'".$key["country"]."', '".$key["open_now"]."','".$key["logo"]."','".$key["groupid"]."','$groupname','".$key["photo_reference"]."', '".$key["website"]."'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT googleid FROM shops WHERE googleid = '".$key["googleid"]."'
) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: You are open to SQL Injection

Comment: it's a development environment

Comment: update your question and show your exact error message  (not only the first part)

Comment: As i couldn't up date the post here is the full error
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT googleid FROM shops WHERE googleid = 'sdfsdfsdfsd' at line 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding a "from 'tablename'" before the "WHERE" clause